# How to create an interactive bash script to collect arguments for a command in linux?

Tags: bash, shell-script, mysql

I'm trying to create an interactive bash script where I can collect user input variables to be used as arguments in another command. Can someone provide me an example of this?

Currently i want to do:

1. what type of content you want to delete?
2. what is the status?

then feed it into a mysql delete query command.

Comment: Are you referring to the command line arguments or input from the user when the script is running?

Answer (score 2):

You can use read or select:

```
read -p prompt answer; echo "$answer"
read -p 'Continue (y/n)? ' -n1 answer; echo; [[ $answer = [yY] ]] || return
```

`PS3='What is the capital of Sweden (1-3)? '; select answer in Gothenburg Stockholm Uppsala; do [[ $answer = Stockholm ]] && { echo Correct; break; } || echo Try again; done`

Answer (score 0):

With the command 'read' you can collect information from input and store it in a variable/file that you can subsequently pass through to your other script.

With the -s option it even masks the user input while typing: great for inputting for example passwords.

Answer (score 0):

For such a job, perhaps a fuller language like Python is a better match. You can call programs from it, or do your dubious deeds directly.